Zener diodes in series with different voltage ratings and same power rating
I want to make a high voltage shunt regulator with a string of series zener diodes of different voltage ratings. There will be some 51 volt diodes and some 40 volt diodes. I am shunting from 800 volts down to 500 volts regulated. My gut instinct thinks that currents and voltages wont be equal and will cause a problem. However I am not sure? Thanks.

use NPN transistors with the zener from base to emmiter, a voltage follower. this lets you heat sink and handle more power for less money than high-power zeners.

In a series circuit, there must be equal current through all series elements. That is also known as the Kirchhoff law for currents, KCL.
However, a Zener diode will only have the rated voltage when the rated current flows through it. And even then the voltage is not exact but within the rated tolerance.

This is technically possible, you could use zener diodes to drop the required voltage to get 500V from 800V. There will be some variation between the diodes, but the more you use, the more the error will start to average out. You'd need to ensure that for all operating conditions, the current through the diodes is within their operating range. This might sound simple, but unless you're current draw is fixed it can become a bit non-trivial.
IMO, this is unlikely to be a practical solution for whatever you're trying to achieve.

+1. If you have $n$ Zener diodes in series whose nominal Zener voltage is $V_Z$ and its absolute tolerance is $\Delta V_Z$, the final series of diodes will reach a total value $V_{Z_n}$ of Zener voltage equal to $$V_{Z_n} = n V_Z \pm \frac{\Delta V_Z}{\sqrt{n}},$$ and if you have for example $n=10$ you can increase significantly the precision of the obtained voltage.

Currents in any series connection, and therefore in yours as well, will be equal.
The voltage drops across Zener diodes should be equal or close to their rated Zener voltages if the current is within their rated current ranges.
Your main problem will be limiting the current through them, and the heat dissipation in them.
It would help if you give us more details, including a schematic or a drawing of a more complete circuit so that we can give you better answers, suggestions or solutions that better suit your needs.

Thanks for the replies. The original circuit for vacuum tube. Its a screen regulator. That requires 1000 volts on the screen. The original circuit used a tube regulator.

Thanks for the replies. The original circuit is for vacuum tube. Its a screen regulator. That requires 1000 volts on the screen. The original circuit used a tube regulator. A brains trusted suggested 1395 dc rectified input to a current limiting resistor of 2.4K. The current will be limited to about 200ma. The brains trust advisor  used a string of 7 X 140 volt 50 NTE zeners. NTE5290. These have become unobtanium. I have 4 of them and some bzy91c51r 51 volt zeners that i want to use  combined in series will deliver a current limited 1000 volts regulator.

@user427440 I have not so long ago purchased 150 V Zener diodes. There are other ways to regulate the high voltage. You could use a high voltage transistor either as a shunt or a series pass regulator, and set its voltage with the common 431 IC. I could draw such two schematics for you, but I would recommend series instead of parallel because you will be wasting up to 200 W or more just on the regulator itself. Even with series regulation, you will have 400 V at up to 0.2 A, which is up to 80 W power dissipated as heat. If supply noise is not an issue, PWM regulator can be used.

@user427440 I am also surprised that a vacuum tube's screen would use up to 200 mA. Must be a larger and more powerful tube.
